# Design Breaks in IE7 and Links Don't work in Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-7

I seem to be having two problems:

1. My top nav bar links don't work in Firefox
2. The design breaks in IE7.

Any help would be much appreciated! I have validated it, and I know the slider and video don't validate, but I still have these problems even when I take those out. Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

http://www.christthesavioracademy.org

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I think you misread.  Question #1 is:My top nav bar links don't work in Firefox. And Question #2 is:The design breaks in IE7.  I should have put a period after Firefox and before the 2. Sorry!

Comment: Yup, I misread. I've removed that comment and edited your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the IE7 problem by making the following changes:

- On `#content`, add `position: relative; padding-top:1px`.
- On `#logo`, remove the `margin` and add `position:absolute; top:0; left:9px`.
- On `#bottomnav`, remove `clear: both`.

I can't reproduce your Firefox issue. If there is still a problem, hopefully the steps above will have helped.

Comment: I don't even know how to thank you! I have spent hours on these two problems - and you have fixed both!  Thank you SO SO much! Is there something I need to know going forward? In other words, how did you know this would fix it, and am I an idiot for not knowing? Thank you and have a great day.

Comment: You're welcome :) The standard way to say thanks here would be to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). You're not an idiot in the slightest - debugging older versions of IE (such as 7) can be very tricky. I used IE9's Developer Tools (hit F12) in "IE7 Mode" to debug your problem, trying out different things. Knowing *what* to change comes from experience, and trial+error.